# Screen flickers in Fedora 17

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, monitors

Screen flickers every 10 seconds. (I timed with a stopwatch, screen flickers every 10 seconds, 6 times a minute exactly.)

I've used Windows and I'm trying to use Linux. I don't know much about Linux. I think maybe this is about monitor frequency. But I don't know how and where I can fix it. But it's just my guess, many other reasons can exist.

When I replaced Linux embedded driver with the NVidia driver, XWindows doesn't boot, I only see the Fedora logo.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Everything up to date? What exact graphics card?